# Why do I get "ld: warning: direct access in _main to global weak symbol" in this simple code?

Tags: c++, xcode, warnings, ld

It's very strange behavior in my Clang compiler. I use Xcode (OS X), all is up-to-date. Why am I getting this warning in that simple code? If I remove those two lines the warning hides.

> ld: warning: direct access in _main to global weak symbol
>   std::__1::char_traits::eq(char, char) means the weak symbol
>   cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different
>   translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    std::string file = "test";
    size_t pos = file.find( "a" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to compile with `-fvisibility=hidden`?

Comment: @sergej Why should I hide this warning? I don't want to just ignore it. I want to find out what's wrong with my code and solve it without hiding it.

Answer (score 9):

See [Controlling Symbol Visibility @ developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/CppRuntimeEnv/Articles/SymbolVisibility.html) for details.

It looks like your libs (eg. the C++ standard library) and your code have been compiled with **different visibility settings**, at least, that is what the linker error message is saying.

To fix the warning, you should use the same visibility settings when compiling your code, eg `-fvisibility=hidden`.

Comment: it's strange but it doesn't fix the warnings

Comment: `-fvisibility=default` maybe?

Comment: default visibility doesn't work either.

Comment: @Zendel see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11879361/1943799